# Flutter ListView Item Click Listener

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a `ListView` and I want to navigate to the next page on the item click.

I need an index of the clicked item of my `ListView`.
I know this can be done using `Controller`. But I couldn't find any example.

Comment: No need for `flutter-sdk` tag, see description for [tag:flutter] tag

Answer (score 64):

When adding the onTap for your GestureRecognizer, (or button), your closure can capture the index passed through in the itemBuilder.

E.g.

```
 body: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                child: Text(index.toString()),
                onTap: () => Scaffold
                    .of(context)
                    .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(index.toString()))),
              );
            },
            itemCount: 10));
```

This code will display a snack bar containing the index of the ListItem that you have tapped.

Once you have the index of the item, you can navigate to a new page using code provided by other answers to this question.

Comment: I would go for `InkWell` rather than `GestureDetector` as it adds a clicking ripple and has `onTap()` as well.

Answer (score 50):

If you're using a `ListView.builder`, you can use a `ListTile` to add an `onTap`. This will make sure you have the material ripple effect.

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (_, i) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('$i'),
      onTap: () {}, // Handle your onTap here. 
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: This is the native way, thanks!

Answer (score 19):

There's an [example](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data) in the Flutter documentation that's actually this very situation (navigation to next page on item click).

As others have said, use the `onTap` on the item in a `ListView.builder`.  Just thought I'd post the link to the example in case someone else needed a more full explanation.

[Send data to a new screen - flutter.io](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data)

```
...    

final List<Todo> todos;

...

ListView.builder(
  itemCount: todos.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(todos[index].title),
      onTap: () {
        //Go to the next screen with Navigator.push
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: @Volleyball The difference was just to include the link and example code from the flutter docs.

Answer (score 14):

Another alternative is to use `InkWell`. `InkWell` includes a nice ripple effect on tap, which `GestureDetector` does not have.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html

Use like this:

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Hello World")),
    body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return InkWell(
            child: Text(index.toString()),
            onTap: () => Scaffold.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(index.toString()))),
          );
        },
        itemCount: 10)
);
```

Comment: @TiagoSantos Could you please refer source about InkWell not working on iOS?

Answer (score 7):

You should use the onPressed method in the item(s) you have in your ListView (or add a GestureDetector) then use Navigator, similar to the snippet below where AboutScreen is the next page you want to go to.

```
onPressed: () {
 Navigator.push(
   context,
   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AboutScreen()),
 );
}
```

Comment: Why down voted ? the answer is correct for navigating to another screen from an item in a ListView (or at least one way of doing it) . Maybe you should explain and perhaps provide a different solution.

Comment: The name of the callback would be depend on how this was implemented, **onPressed** was used as an example if the item in the ListView is a button of some sort (FlatButton, IconButton etc.). If you use a GestureDetector then you could use **onTap**. You would need to look at the Class documentation to see which callback was most appropriate for your use case.

Answer (score 5):

[image]**ListViewpage.dart**

```
        class sta extends StatefulWidget {
          const sta({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
        
          @override
          State<sta> createState() => _staState();
        }
        
        var isShow = false;
        var getdata = Diohelper.getdata();
        
        class _staState extends State<sta> {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            List mwidge = [];
            int index = 0;
            getdata.forEach((element) {
              element.index = index;
              mwidge.add(ListTile(

                onTap: () {
// on click listner for move to another widget or activity (android native)
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
    // here element passing to the detail page element contain index other details
    DetailPage(element)));
                },
                hoverColor: Colors.amber,
                title: Text(element.name.toString()),
                trailing: element.isShow
                    ? SizedBox(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 50,
                        child: OutlinedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                  SnackBar(content: Text(element.name.toString())));
                            },
                            child: Text("Show")),
                      )
                    : Container(
                        width: 100,
                      ),
              ));
              index++;
            });
            return GestureDetector(
              child: Center(
                child: ListView(
                  children: [...mwidge],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

**DetailPage.dart**

```
class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  productModel model;

  DetailPage(this.model, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DetailPageState createState() => _DetailPageState();
}

class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Text("Name:" + widget.model.name.toString()),
              Text("Category:" + widget.model.category.toString()),
              Text("price:" + widget.model.price.toString())
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

**FullCode:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() =>
    runApp(MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(), body: sta())));

class sta extends StatefulWidget {
  const sta({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<sta> createState() => _staState();
}

var isShow = false;
var getdata = Diohelper.getdata();

class _staState extends State<sta> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List mwidge = [];
    int index = 0;
    getdata.forEach((element) {
      element.index = index;
      mwidge.add(ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage(element)));
        },
        hoverColor: Colors.amber,
        title: Text(element.name.toString()),
        trailing: element.isShow
            ? SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                height: 50,
                child: OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          SnackBar(content: Text(element.name.toString())));
                    },
                    child: Text("Show")),
              )
            : Container(
                width: 100,
              ),
      ));
      index++;
    });
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Center(
        child: ListView(
          children: [...mwidge],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  productModel model;

  DetailPage(this.model, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DetailPageState createState() => _DetailPageState();
}

class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Text("Name:" + widget.model.name.toString()),
              Text("Category:" + widget.model.category.toString()),
              Text("price:" + widget.model.price.toString())
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class productModel {
  String? name;
  String? price;
  String? category;
  bool isShow = false;
  int index = 0;

  productModel({this.name, this.price, this.category, this.isShow = false});

  productModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    price = json['price'];
    category = json['category'];
    isShow = json['isShow'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    data['category'] = this.category;
    data['isShow'] = this.isShow;
    return data;
  }
}

class Diohelper {
  static List<productModel> getdata() {
    List<productModel> list = [];
    list.add(productModel(name: "broast", price: "100", category: "chicken"));
    list.add(productModel(name: "mandi", price: "100", category: "chicken"));
    list.add(productModel(name: "mandi", price: "100", category: "veg"));

    return list;
  }
}
```

[Dartpad or Live Code](https://dartpad.dev/?id=a31c6bdedf066f8a5b49baec3188987c)

Comment: use `ScaffoldMessenger` instead of Scaffold. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldMessengerState/showSnackBar.html

Answer (score 1):

With listview in you can useing GestureDetetor();

```
child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return new GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => RoomDetail()));
                      },
                      child: Container(child:(Text("This is content you want")));
```